# Log4j.Appender = java.util.logging.FileHandler?

Tags: java, logging, properties, configuration, log4j

I'm trying to switch from java.util.logging to Log4j but I don't understand how I'm suppose to switch everything.

Using java.util.logging, I have a logger and a handler. When the handler is set, I add it to my logger. But I can't find "handlers stuff" in Log4j? Is it the same as Appender?

In my property file, I need to write

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log = /usr/home/log4j
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=myPath

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

... but I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find "handlers stuff" in Log4j? Is it the same as Appender?

Yes.  In Log4j there is a concept of an [appender-ref](https://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat) which is not present in java.util.logging.  This allows you to make multiple handlers of the same class with different configurations.  It might be easier to understand if you look at the xml example first instead of a properties example.

In your example, `FILE` is just a name of the appender-ref which is added to the key namespace to make it unique under the properties format.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yeah I did a lot of research since I asked and I ended up doing all this programmatically! I think it was way more easy to understand that way!